# How to check If a multiline String contains another multiline String in Java?

Tags: java, string, contains, multilinestring

1.I tried to use the contains function BUT it did not work, it only works when b = "30-10-1960\n"  or b = "Posephine Esmerelda Bloggs\n". How to check if a contains b?
2.Here is the code I wrote.

```
String a = "name Posephine Esmerelda Bloggs\n" + 
        "birthday 30-10-1960\n" + 
        "address 102 Smith St, Summer hill, NSW 2130\n" + 
        "";
String b = "Posephine Esmerelda Bloggs\n" + 
        "30-10-1960\n";
System.out.println("a.contains(b)");
```

Comment: But there is no such substring `b` in the string `a`. In the second line "birthday " is missing.

Comment: It doesn't works because `Posephine Esmerelda Bloggs\nbirthday 30-10-1960\n` is not `Posephine Esmerelda Bloggs\n30-10-1960\n`. You missed the `birthday`part

Comment: A `\n` in a String is just a character. Having this character in a `contains` parameter doesn't mean it will check for 2 differents String.

Comment: 1.  The String `a` does not contains the String `b`.  2. Your print is emitting a string - it is not invoking the `contains` method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the logic you want here is to assert that every *line* of the `b` string appears somewhere in the `a` string:

```
String a = "name Posephine Esmerelda Bloggs\n" + 
    "birthday 30-10-1960\n" + 
    "address 102 Smith St, Summer hill, NSW 2130\n" + 
    "";
String b = "Posephine Esmerelda Bloggs\n" + 
    "30-10-1960\n";
String[] lines = b.split("\n");

// now check each line
boolean all = true;
for (String line : lines) {
    if (!a.contains(line)) {
        all = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (all) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

This prints:

```
MATCH
```

Comment: What is obviously wrong, because b is *not* included in a?

Comment: It was not wrong.. My logic is to find every line of the b string appears somewhere in the a string.. That is exactly what he said.

Comment: Since the order is not checked (`"30-10-1960\nPosephine Esmerelda Bloggs\n"` is found too), it is only a search for two strings.

Answer (score 0):

it works try this -

```
String a = "name Posephine Esmerelda Bloggs\n" + 
            "birthday 30-10-1960\n" + 
            "address 102 Smith St, Summer hill, NSW 2130\n" + 
            "";
    String b = "Posephine Esmerelda Bloggs\n" + 
            "birthday 30-10-1960\n";
    System.out.println(a.contains(b));
```

in your code there is some issue - 
1. you used as a string literals in println method, it must be a reference.
2. what you are comparing is not same. In 'a' there is extra word 'birthday' that is missing in 'b'.

The correct string sequence i pasted in sample code.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I don't think to parse or do anything. the same code will work. I share corrected code as well i did not only comment on.

Answer (score -2):

*for the answer of the question how to find the two parts in b*

```
String[] arr = b.split( "\n" );
int pos = a.indexOf( arr[0] + '\n' );
if( pos > -1 && a.indexOf( arr[1] + '\n', pos ) > -1 )
  System.err.println( "found" );
```

`+ '\n'`: finds the parts only if they end with a `\n`
if the check for the ending `'\n'` is unnecessary remove both `+ '\n'`
if the parts may be unordered the `pos` argument can be omitted

*without checking for the `\n` at the end or the order as in the chosen solution*

```
String[] arr = b.split( "\n" );
if( a.indexOf( arr[0] ) > -1 && a.indexOf( arr[1] ) > -1 )
  System.err.println( "found" );
```

*the solution without checking is identical to the following*

```
 if( a.contains( arr[0] ) && a.contains( arr[1] ) )
   System.err.println( "found" );
```

*…because* `contains(s)` *returns* `indexOf(s.toString()) > -1`